# How to rotate UIImage in image center

Tags: iphone, uiimage

```
double angle = -15;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
CGSize s = {image.size.width, image.size.height};
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(s);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0,image.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, 2*M_PI*angle/360);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx,CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width, image.size.height),image.CGImage);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hi,I wont to rotate UIImage in image center point. I can rotate UIImage with this code,but not in center point.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Use Core Animation.  You can say

UIView.layer.anchor = aPoint;

Then, preform the rotation using the CA framework, and it will happen around that anchor.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work but only with UIImageOrientation = 0,

```c
// Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

//Rotate the image context
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, rad(degrees));

// Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-self.size.width / 2, -self.size.height / 2,     self.size.width, self.size.height), [self CGImage]);
```